# angularJS translation with pascalprecht.translate - language files

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I use pascalprecht.translate for translating and I have a problem with the properties- filenames. 
I use the following configuration:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('aposoft.lang')
    .config(configure);

configure.$inject =['$translateProvider'];

function configure($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        files: [{
            prefix: 'app/lang/i18n/lang-',
            suffix: '.json'
        }]
    });

    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');
    $translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage();
    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
}
```

})();

and the problem is that I need the property- filename **lang-en_EN.json** for Firefox and **lang-en.json** e.g. for Chrome.

My question now would be how to prevent of having two i18n properties files and only have one file?

Comment: This is my config and I only have 1 file for all browsers.  
  ``` 
         $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
      prefix: 'assets/i18n/locale-',
      suffix: '.json'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
      ```

Answer (score 0):

This is my config and I only have 1 file for all browsers.

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
  prefix: 'assets/i18n/locale-',
  suffix: '.json'
});

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
```

I don't have these two config settings:

```
$translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage();
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
```